# interface between two libraries

Tags: api

For the next few months I will be  needing to use PETSc and SuperLU_DIST together. On the PETSc webpage they give a list of software to which PETSc "interfaces" one of which is SuperLU_DIST.

I am not really sure what is meant by the word "interface". I mean both libraries have been written in C. So surely if I write a C code and include the appropriate header files of PETSc and SuperLU surely they can pass arguments and between each others functions.

Forgive me if this sounds like a stupid question but I have not really used numerical software packages/libraries before in my own codes and I am fairly new to prgramming.

Thank you

Comment: Add the language or API to your tags, please.

Answer (score 0):

PETSc integrates some solvers into its KSP module, which implements some Krylow space methods. Of course, the KSP module allows you to use some preconditioning methods. Third-party solvers, like SuperLU, are implemented as preconditioners.

The basic strategy is to set up a KSP object and a PC (Preconditioner) object with your favored solver. Then you make KSP to use only the PC by setting its type to KSPPREONLY (only preconditioning).

Below is a working example I used for MUMPS. Of course, you can do faster if you solve multiple systems of the same type, etc.. You should consult the PETSc manual and modify the code to fit your needs.

```
Vec
solveWithMumps(const Mat mat, const Vec rhs)
{
  MPI_Comm mpi_comm;
  PETSC_WRAP(PetscObjectGetComm(
          reinterpret_cast<PetscObject>(mat), &mpi_comm));

  Vec solution;
  PETSC_WRAP(MatGetVecs(mat, &solution, PETSC_NULL));

  KSP ksp;
  PETSC_WRAP(KSPCreate(mpi_comm, &ksp));
  PETSC_WRAP(KSPSetOperators(ksp, mat, mat, DIFFERENT_NONZERO_PATTERN));

  PC pc;
  PETSC_WRAP(KSPGetPC(ksp, &pc));
  PETSC_WRAP(KSPSetType(ksp, KSPPREONLY));
  PETSC_WRAP(PCSetType(pc, PCLU));
  PETSC_WRAP(PCFactorSetMatSolverPackage(pc, MAT_SOLVER_MUMPS));
  PETSC_WRAP(KSPSetFromOptions(ksp));
  PETSC_WRAP(KSPSolve(ksp, rhs, solution));
  PETSC_WRAP(KSPDestroy(ksp));

  return solution;
}
```